# UI-Router nested templates parent variable change not reflected in child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

States declared like this. As you can see there is a state called "market" with a sub-state called "list". They share the controller, but have different templates.

```
.state('market', {
            url: '/market',
            templateUrl: '/market',
            controller: 'MarketController',
            access: { requiredLogin: true }
        }).state('market.list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: '/market/list',
            controller: 'MarketController',
            access: { requiredLogin: true }
        })
```

In the controller I have declared a variable, $scope.activeProduct, whose value can be modified by clicking on a button in the "market.*".

**I have placed {{activeProduct}} in both of the templates. When the button is clicked, the value only changes in the "market.*" part.**

This is the function that is triggered upon clicking the button:

```
        $scope.switchProduct = function (id) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.activeProduct = id;
                    MarketStorageService.activeProduct = id;
                    console.log("activeproduct changed to" + id);
                }
            );
        });
    };
```

I just don't understand why in the "market.list" the value does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the common gotcha of scope inheritance in angular. The child state's scope has its own copy of `activeProduct`, and so when it changes the inheritance chain is not consulted about the change. This is all explained pretty well in [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). A quick fix would be to reference the variable on the parent scope:

`$scope.$parent.activeProduct;`

In the child state.

Comment: Thanks! 15 character minimummmmm